# Numerical integration: how to include a boundary condition in a set of initial conditions

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, nonlinear-system, boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems

I am facing a problem with a numerical integration on Mathematica. I want to integrate the following system of two nonlinear 2nd order equations
$$f''(x)+\lambda f'(x)=-\alpha \left(\frac{g'(x)^2}{f(x)}+2\frac{g(x)^2}{f(x)}+\frac{2 g(x)^2g'(x)}{f'(x)^2}\right)$$
and
$$g''(x)-\frac{f'(x) g'(x)}{f(x)}-2 \frac{g(x) g'(x)}{f(x)}-2 g(x)=0$$

($\alpha$ and $\lambda$ are constant parameters) whose initial conditions are $f(0)=0, f'(0)=1, g(0)=1$ and $g'(0)$ is adjustable so that one must achieve the asymptotic behavior $g(\infty)\to 0$. However I am not succeeding in obtaining such expected behaviour at infinity by merely adjusting $g'(0)$. So I am wondering if there was any specific procedure to include the condition $g(\infty)\to 0$ along with the initial conditions, in order to compel such a behavior. I'd be happy with any help on this issue. Cheers.

Comment: Have you tried posting your question and code on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57262/how-to-solve-ode-with-boundary-at-infinity may be of interest.

Comment: Thank you, guys! In fact I did not solve the problem directly, but in the particular case I'm dealing with I found a way to avoid it instead (at least it for a while). If necessary I post the code on the link indicated above. Cheers.